# On Node MySQL vs JSON

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I'm currently using a MySQL where do I store JSON information and I'd fetch them from MySQL and parse them on my application. I would like to get rid of MySQL, but first I would like to know is that wise?

Is that efficient if I move to way that I store the data into data folder that contains .json files and these contains the data I need? There will be my app's coordinate data per user who wants to track themselves on map. Will that cause any issues? I don't need "query", but what about big data like 50K lines in example? Same amount will be in MySQL too. Amount doesn't change, but will there be any problems that appears when moving from "reading from sql to reading from json files"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to answer all these questions in one, but I'll address some of them:

- There are dedicated NoSQL databases that are very good at the type of data storage you're talking about: [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/), [CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/) etc. It might be worth checking these out. They are very good at dealing with JSON data. Querying and parsing are very simple in Node.js.
- You *can* store JSON in MySQL (or other RDMS systems), I've done it in several projects with good results. As of MySQL 5.7.8 there is a dedicated [JSON type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html). Queries can actually work surprisingly well, I know I've queried tables with tens of millions of JSON entries pretty quickly.
- Make sure you consider backup and restore scenarios, what happens in the event of a data loss. Using MySQL or a NoSQL database will simplify this for you. Either way make sure you have this covered!
- I wouldn't call 50K lines big data! I dealt with databases with tens of millions of rows.. this still wouldn't be called big data.
- I would probably not recommend storing your data in files. I've worked in telematics before, we stored millions of JSON blobs in relational databases with very little problems. Later on we planned to move to a NoSQL database for these, but the relational database worked surprising well, especially because you can adopt a hybrid approach of using relational queries and including JSON data in the results (to be parsed by clients).
- You might not need the ability to query, but it's very useful to get for example "Give me all JSON for user id 100". An RDBMS or NoSQL system would make this very easy.

Comment: Is there any problem on Node.js when handling JSON files with nearly 200K of rows or similar?

Comment: I don't believe so, that isn't really that much data. You might end up using a reasonably large amount of memory, but on a modern machine it's not going to be that taxing. I'd suggest creating some mock test data and measure how long this will take. I don't expect it will be too much (depending on how big the rows are of course!)